# Why don't replace Resources file in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I created a resources file in SharePoint to display column names into several languages. The problem is when i edit resource file it does not work and i had to create a new file every time.

How should i replace resources file with a new file and same name?

Comment: How did you do this? Did you create resources file and put it  to the Resource folder by hand? Did you recycle the IIS?

Comment: Yes,i put it to the Resource folder by hand but i don't recycle the IIS.

Comment: I think that you should try it :)